# Permission denied running Terraform import

Tags: terraform

I have successfully used Terraform import on one AWS account where my credentials were admin. I'm now trying to run the command on a different account, where I have more limited permissions.

Does anyone know specially what AWS policy is needed to run Terraform import?

Comment: Does the error message returned not say what action was being attempted when permission was denied?

Comment: Error importing: 1 error(s) occurred:
* provider.aws: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid. status code: 403, request id: <>

Answer (score 3):

Set the `TF_LOG` environment variable to `DEBUG` before your run Terraform.

This will out the exact call that is returning 403.

Comment: Thanks. Ran it and it says the security token is invalid. I'll just have to run my import on a Jenkins box since I can't get it to run locally.